# Improper Shooting Direction cocos2D-iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

```
Bows rotates 360 Degree using touch and it fires arrow while touch ended.

Moving portion works perfectly but their need some correction while touch endes..
The problem is while i touch the bow,moving direction of arrow is opposite to bow such as
```

[image]

while i rotate bow in opposite direction then it works fine,,but only when bow rotates .. Arrow should fires from right to left and Bow's position should be right.

What correction should i do to make them possible together.?!
Sorry,for my english..

My code as as below..

```
-(void) ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    [self setArrowFromPt:location centerPt:windowCenter];
}

-(void) setArrowFromPt:(CGPoint)touchPt centerPt:(CGPoint)centerPt
{
    diff = ccpSub(touchPt, centerPt);
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(diff));

    angle = ccpToAngle(diff);
    normalized = ccpNormalize(diff);

    float START_ANGLE = 0;
    float RADIUS = 100.0;

    imgArrow.position = ccpAdd(centerPt, ccpMult(normalized, RADIUS));
    cocosAngle = -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle);
    imgArrow.rotation = START_ANGLE + cocosAngle;
}

-(void) ccTouchEnded:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    cocosAngle =  -CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(angle);
    curangle = imgArrow.rotation;
    CGFloat rotateDiff = cocosAngle - curangle;  
    CGFloat rotateSpeed = 180; 
    rotateDuration = fabs(rotateDiff / rotateSpeed);

    if (_nextProjectile != nil) return;
    _nextProjectile = [[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"newarrow.png"] retain];
    _nextProjectile.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
    _nextProjectile.position = ccp(380,150);

    [imgArrow runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                       [CCRotateTo actionWithDuration:rotateDuration angle:cocosAngle],
                       [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishShoot)],
                       nil]]; 

    ccTime delta = 1.0;
    CGPoint normalizedShootVector = ccpNormalize(diff);
    CGPoint overshotVector = ccpMult(normalizedShootVector, 420);
    CGPoint offscreenPoint = ccpAdd(_nextProjectile.position, overshotVector);

    [_nextProjectile runAction:[CCSequence actions:
                                [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:delta position:offscreenPoint],
                                [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(spriteMoveFinished:)],
                                nil]];
    _nextProjectile.tag = 2;

}
```

any help is Appreciated.
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i can give answer to my question,

i have solve my problem by just correcting

**CGPoint overshotVector = ccpMult(normalizedShootVector, -420);**

putting - sign,causes my arrow throwing from right to left direction.